# Override tinymce 4 spellchecker method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, tinymce-4

I'm trying to override the default TinyMce 4 spellchecker method "markErrors", but without success.

I've already tried:

```
// on editor init...
editor.plugins.spellchecker.markErrors = function() {
    alert(123);

    return false;
}
```

The above method actually replace the plugin object value, but it is not used by the spellchecker (maybe I need to reinit the spellchecker itself somehow...).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the plugin source code, I think that actually it is not possible to override this method **(without editing the source)**.

The main problem came from that the call

```
sendRpcCall("spellcheck", getTextMatcher().text, markErrors, errorCallback);
```

is before the assignment

```
this.markErrors = markErrors;
```

which enables to override the method with

```
editor.plugins.spellchecker.markErrors = function() {...}
```

but will be never used by the plugin itself.